# Can I start the new Android subscription functionality after a 30 day trial period?

Tags: android

I'm looking at using the new subscription functionality in Android.  My question is this: Can I start the subscription after a 30 trial?

Here's how I'd like it to work:

1. The user downloads the app
2. The app says the subscription will start in 30 days unless you unsubscribe
3. 30 days from when they downloaded the app, it automatically starts billing them using the new Android subscription service.

Anyone????  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing stops you from starting the subscription process whenever you want.

I'm working on an app that has a similar way of functioning, but instead of 30 days trial I have to ask for a subscription after an action is repeated a certain number of times.

The "catch" is that you have to handle the time passage yourself either locally or on the server side of your app, and when the time is right pop the question: would you like to keep using this app? then let me see the cash; and depending on the answer, either deliver or not deliver content to the user

implementation basics at http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html